Anyone doing Indooratlas integration into existing React Native application?
I have an error while building the app for android:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.


Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not find com.indooratlas.android:indooratlas-android-sdk:3.6.11.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/indooratlas/android/indooratlas-android-sdk/3.6.11/indooratlas-android-sdk-3.6.11.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/indooratlas/android/indooratlas-android-sdk/3.6.11/indooratlas-android-sdk-3.6.11.pom
- file:/Users/prajaychaudhary/Desktop/Indooratlas-map-integration-react-native/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/indooratlas/android/indooratlas-android-sdk/3.6.11/indooratlas-android-sdk-3.6.11.pom
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/indooratlas/android/indooratlas-android-sdk/3.6.11/indooratlas-android-sdk-3.6.11.pom
- https://www.jitpack.io/com/indooratlas/android/indooratlas-android-sdk/3.6.11/indooratlas-android-sdk-3.6.11.pom
Required by:
project :app > project :react-native-indooratlas


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
13 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 10 up-to-date
I followed the steps : text and even added in the android/build.gradle file as:
maven {           url "https://dl.cloudsmith.io/public/indooratlas/mvn-public/maven/"
}
but seems it doesn't search into the maven repo.
Thanks in advance!
